Correcting tag synonyms
I asked a question which I tagged to forensic-psychology and criminology as the question related to both disciplines.  I went to create a tag wiki for criminology and I found that it has been linked to forensic-psychology (as synonyms of each other), removing the criminology tag from my question.
Criminology and Forensic Psychology are 2 different disciplines.
Criminology is:

the scientific study of the nature, extent, management, causes, control, consequences, and prevention of criminal behavior, both on the individual and social levels. Criminology is an interdisciplinary field in both the behavioral and social sciences, drawing especially upon the research of sociologists, psychologists, philosophers, psychiatrists, social anthropologists, as well as scholars of law.

Forensic Psychology is:

the intersection between psychology and the justice system. It involves understanding fundamental legal principles, particularly with regard to expert witness testimony and the specific content area of concern (e.g., competence to stand trial, child custody and visitation, or workplace discrimination), as well as relevant jurisdictional considerations (e.g., in the United States, the definition of insanity in criminal trials differs from state to state) in order to be able to interact appropriately with judges, attorneys, and other legal professionals.

in fact.. (emphasis mine)

Questions asked by the court of a forensic psychologist are generally not questions regarding psychology but are legal questions and the response must be in language the court understands. For example, a forensic psychologist is frequently appointed by the court to assess a defendant's competence to stand trial. The court also frequently appoints a forensic psychologist to assess the state of mind of the defendant at the time of the offense. This is referred to as an evaluation of the defendant's sanity or insanity (which relates to criminal responsibility) at the time of the offense. These are not primarily psychological questions but rather legal ones. Thus, a forensic psychologist must be able to translate psychological information into a legal framework.

This makes me wonder if the forensic-psychology tag is on-topic within this site and that things should be the other way round (the forensic-psychology tag should be linked to criminology instead of criminology being linked to forensic-psychology)
How can we have this corrected?

I swapped the tags but it may take the system a while to put this through. Let me know when the tags are swapped and I can set this question on status completed.

My apologies for posting this answer on your question on the main site. You accepted it there, but I removed that answer nonetheless, as it doesn't answer your main post in any way :)
